# Combinations & Numpy

Tags: numpy, combinations, python-itertools

I need to rate each combination in order to get the best one.

I completed the first step but it is not optimized at all.

When the value of RQ or NBPIS or NBSER is big, my code is much too long.

Do you have an idea to get the same result much faster?

Thank you very much

```
    import numpy as np    
    from itertools import combinations, combinations_with_replacement
    
    #USER SETTINGS
    
    RQ=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']
    NBPIS=3
    NBSER=3
    
    #CODE
    
    Combi1=np.array(list(combinations_with_replacement(RQ,NBPIS)))  
    Combi2=combinations_with_replacement(Combi1,NBSER)
    Combi3=np.array([])

    Compt=0
    First=0

    for X in Combi2:
        
        Long=0
        Compt=Compt+1
        Y=np.array(X)
            
        for Z in RQ:
            
            Long=Long+1
            
            if Z not in Y:
                break
            
            elif Long==len(RQ):
               
                if First==0:
                    Combi3=Y
                    Combi3 = np.expand_dims(Combi3, axis = 0)
                    First=1
                    
                else:
                    Combi3=np.append(Combi3, [Y], axis = 0)
    
    #RESULTS
    
    print(Combi3)
    print(Combi3.shape)          
    print(Compt)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your code produces the desirable result, the first step to optimize your code is refactoring it. This might help others to jump in and help as well.
Let's start making a function of it.

```
#USER SETTINGS
RQ=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']
NBPIS=3
NBSER=3

def your_code():
    Combi1=np.array(list(combinations_with_replacement(RQ,NBPIS)))
    Combi2=combinations_with_replacement(Combi1,NBSER)
    Combi3=np.array([])

    Compt=0
    First=0
    for X in Combi2:
        Long=0
        Compt=Compt+1
        Y=np.array(X)
        for Z in RQ:
            Long=Long+1
            if Z not in Y:
                break
            elif Long==len(RQ):
                if First==0:
                    Combi3=Y
                    Combi3 = np.expand_dims(Combi3, axis = 0)
                    First=1
                else:
                    Combi3=np.append(Combi3, [Y], axis = 0)

    shape = Combi3.shape 
    size = Compt
    return Combi3, shape, size
```

### Refactoring

Notice that `Compt` is equal to `len(Combi2)`, so turning `Combi2` as a numpy array will help to simplify the code. This also allow the variable `Y` to be replaced by `X` only. Also, there is no need for `Combi1` to be a numpy array since it is only consumed by `combinations_with_replacement`.

```
def your_code_refactored():
    Combi1 = combinations_with_replacement(RQ,NBPIS)
    Combi2 = np.array(list(combinations_with_replacement(Combi1,NBSER)))
    Combi3=np.array([])

    First=0
    for X in Combi2:
        Long=0
        for Z in RQ:
            Long=Long+1
            if Z not in X:
                break
            elif Long==len(RQ):
                if First==0:
                    Combi3=X
                    Combi3 = np.expand_dims(Combi3, axis = 0)
                    First=1
                else:
                    Combi3=np.append(Combi3, [X], axis = 0)

    shape = Combi3.shape 
    size = len(Combi2)
    return Combi3, shape, size
```

Next thing is to refactor how `Combi3` is created and populated. The varialbe `First` is used to expand `Combi3` dimension in the first interaction only, so this logic can be simplified as,

```
def your_code_refactored():
    Combi1 = combinations_with_replacement(RQ,NBPIS)
    Combi2 = np.array(list(combinations_with_replacement(Combi1,NBSER)))
    Combi3 = np.empty((0, NBPIS, NBSER))

    for X in Combi2:
        Long=0
        for Z in RQ:
            Long=Long+1
            if Z not in X:
                break
            elif Long==len(RQ):
                Combi3 = np.append(Combi3, [X], axis = 0)

    shape = Combi3.shape 
    size = len(Combi2)
    return Combi3, shape, size
```

It seems `Combi2` is populated only with combinations that have at least one of each element from `RQ`. This is accomplished by testing if each element of `RQ` is in `X`, which is basically checking if `RQ` is a subset of `X`. So it is simplified further,

```
def your_code_refactored():
    Combi1 = combinations_with_replacement(RQ,NBPIS)
    Combi2 = np.array(list(combinations_with_replacement(Combi1,NBSER)))
    Combi3 = np.empty((0, NBPIS, NBSER))

    unique_RQ = set(RQ)
    for X in Combi2:
        if unique_RQ.issubset(X.flatten()):
            Combi3 = np.append(Combi3, [X], axis = 0)

    shape = Combi3.shape 
    size = len(Combi2)
    return Combi3, shape, size
```

This looks much simpler. Time to make it faster, maybe :)

#### Optimizing

One way this code can be optimized is to replace `np.append` by `list.append`. In numpy's [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) we see that `np.append` reallocate a larger and larger array each time it is called. The code might be speed up with `list.append`, since it over-allocates memory. So the code could be rewritten with list comprehension.

```
def your_code_refactored_and_optimized():
    Combi1 = combinations_with_replacement(RQ,NBPIS)
    Combi2 = np.array(list(combinations_with_replacement(Combi1,NBSER)))

    unique_RQ = set(RQ)
    Combi3 = np.array([X for X in Combi2 if unique_RQ.issubset(X.flatten())])

    shape = Combi3.shape 
    size = len(Combi2)
    return Combi3, shape, size
```

#### Testing

Now we can see it run faster.

```
import timeit
n = 5
print(timeit.timeit('your_code()', globals=globals(), number=n))
print(timeit.timeit('your_code_refactored_and_optimized()', globals=globals(), number=n))
```

This isn't much a gain in speed but it's something :)

Comment: Exactly,

i couldn't compare the values ​​between RQ and Combi2 because of the sublists, i had worked around this problem by converting Combi2 to numpy.

So conversion with set(RQ),.flatten() smooth sublists into a main list, and .issubset compares RQ and Combi2 with the for loop compressed into one line of code.

Well done ! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea to reduce execution time by removing unnecessary combinations, simplifying with the following example with :

```
RQ=['A','B','C']
NBPIS=3
NBSER=3
```

---

Currently with :

```
Combi1 = combinations_with_replacement(RQ,NBPIS)
print(list(Combi1))
```

> [('A', 'A', 'A'), ('A', 'A', 'B'), ('A', 'A', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'B'),
> ('A', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'C', 'C'), ('B', 'B', 'B'), ('B', 'B', 'C'),
> ('B', 'C', 'C'), ('C', 'C', 'C')]

---

But with :

```
Combi1 = list(list(combinations(RQ,W)) for W in range(1,NBPIS+1))
print(Combi1)
```

> [[('A',), ('B',), ('C',)], [('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'C')],
> [('A', 'B', 'C')]]

---

Problem with :

```
Combi1 = list(list(combinations(RQ,W)) for W in range(1,NBPIS+1))
```

> Error message :
>
> Combi3 = np.array([X for X in Combi2 if
> unique_RQ.issubset(X.flatten())])
>
> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

---

But with :

```
(Combi1 = combinations(RQ,W) for W in range(1,NBPIS+1))
print(Combi3)
```

> []

---

Questions :

1. For Combi1,

Instead of :

> [[('A',), ('B',), ('C',)], [('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'C')],
> [('A', 'B', 'C')]]

how to get this ? :

> [('A'), ('B'), ('C'), ('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'C'), ('A', 'B',
> 'C')]

2. For Combi3, is it possible to get an array with different sizes ?

Instead of :

> [[['A' 'A' 'A']   ['A' 'A' 'A']   ['A' 'B' 'C']]...

Obtain this ? :

> [[['A']   ['A']   ['A' 'B' 'C']]...